# Derived Geometry and Deformation Quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, geometry

Can anyone please explain to me in layman' terms what derived geometry deals with and what deformation Quantization is? I have only a good understanding of Relativity,Classical Mechanics.

Comment: This might be too broad.

Comment: @Danu: I understand that it concerns a Poisson Manifold. By Deformation, does it mean that the Poisson Manifold undergoes a deformation?

Comment: You are unhappy with the [WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space_formulation)?